# Conditional concatenation breaks if value is nothing

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to concatenate a string on the end of a sum, but if the sum is nothing, it breaks. It seems like this is due to SSRS evaluating both conditions of the IIf statement, but I can't figure out how to get around this.

I've got....

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Work.Value)), "", Sum(Fields!Work.Value).ToString + " J")
```

Which will print out the `work summary + " J"` if there is one, and `#Error` if not. What's the **SSRS** workaround?

**Update / Clarification**

The report in question is grouping on dates and then summing up `Work`, so it's not the case that `Work` is null, per se, but that for this particular date for this particular user, there are no rows in the group.. So, there are no rows to sum up in the error causing instance.

**Sample Data Set**

```
Name    Date        Work
Andy    12/1/15     511.30
Andy    12/1/15     549.70
Drew    12/2/15     484.80
Drew    12/2/15     322.36
```

**Sample Report (current)**

```
Name    12/1/15     12/2/15    
Andy     1061 J      #Error
Drew     #Error    807.16 J
```

**Sample Report (expected)**

```
Name    12/1/15     12/2/15    
Andy     1061 J     
Drew               807.16 J
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered doing the two parts of your desired output in two different expressions in the same Cell?

I assume for the current structure you have used a matrix, with Rows for the Name, and Columns for the date.  You can the set the Data to be Sum of Work, as shown here, and in the red text in the image below.

```
=Sum(Fields!Work.Value)
```

You then then right click the cell and select "Create Placeholder" to insert a second expression in the same cell.

[image]

Set the value of this expression to be as shown here, and in the blue text below

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!Work.Value) > 0, " J", "")
```

Then when the report is run, it will always show the Sum if there is one, and if the value of the Sum is greater than zero, it will also display the `J` as required.

[image]

Hopefully this is the behaviour you require.  Please let me know if you require further assistance with this solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Isnothing(Fields!Total.Value),0,Fields!Total.Value)) = 0,
"", 
SUM(IIF(Isnothing(Fields!Total.Value),0,Fields!Total.Value)).ToString + " J"
)
```

Let me know if this can help you

Comment: Does your dataset return null when there is no value?

Comment: That's correct, and I know that ISNOTHING is returning true and false as expected.

Comment: I've tested my solution with null values too and it works. Share a sample of your dataset with rows where `Work` column is null.

Comment: I've added a sample data set and sample expected report, as well as a clarification because I think I may have confused myself and been a bit misleading

Answer (score 0):

[IIF does not short-circuit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) so this `#Error` is from SSRS trying to use the `ToString` function on NULLs.

The workaround is to add another `IsNothing` check in the false section before using `ToString`:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Work.Value))
, ""
, IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Work.Value)), "", Sum(Fields!Work.Value)).ToString & " J")
```

Comment: if `IIf`s don't short circuit, then won't the second `IIf` fail just the same?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this exact problem, because if there is no `Work` to display then the report should display nothing, instead of using the IIf statement with concatenation, it is simple and sufficient to set a conditional visibility on the cell.

In the cell, use the expression:

`Sum(Fields!Work.Value).ToString + " J"`

Then for the same cell, select:

`Text Box Properties > Visibility > Show or hide based on an expression`

and enter:

`=IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Work.Value))`

While this solves this specific problem, if the solution requires the empty cell to display anything other than blank, then the original IIf short-circuit issue is still an issue.